# Effects of a transaction begin within a for (nhibernate c#)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

i have the code

```
vendasDoPdv.ForEach(vendaPdv =>
{

if (IgnoraNessaSincronizacao(vendaPdv))
return;

        var ecfCompativel = BuscaEcfCompativelDoAdm(emissoresDoAdm, vendaPdv);
        if (ecfCompativel == null)
            return;

        PessoaDt pessoaComaptivel = null;

        if (vendaPdv.ClienteDt != null)
            pessoaComaptivel = BuscaPessoaCompativel(vendaPdv);

        if (vendaPdv.ClienteDt != null && pessoaComaptivel == null)
            return;

        var transacaoAdm = SessaoAdm.BeginTransaction();
        var transacaoPdv = SessaoPdv.BeginTransaction();

        var vendaAdm = CriarVendaAdm(vendaPdv, pessoaComaptivel, ecfCompativel);

        try
        {
            PersitirVenda(vendaPdv, vendaAdm);
            EnviarItens(vendaPdv.VendaEcfItens, vendaAdm);
            EnviarPagamentos(vendaPdv.VendaEcfPagamentos, vendaAdm);

            transacaoAdm.Commit();
            transacaoPdv.Commit();
            RegistraEvento = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transacaoPdv.Rollback();
            transacaoAdm.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    });
```

what happens
to perform transacaoAdm.Rollback(); he threw an exception

and not run rollback

exception

```
21/02/2016 09:44:33:Serviço iniciou uma sincronização
21/02/2016 09:44:33:Serviço concluiu com exito a sincronização
21/02/2016 09:45:34:Serviço iniciou uma sincronização
21/02/2016 09:45:34:Serviço concluiu com exito a sincronização
21/02/2016 09:46:35:Serviço iniciou uma sincronização
21/02/2016 09:55:12:Serviço falhou na sincronizacao
21/02/2016 09:55:12:Mensagem de erro: Transaction not successfully started
21/02/2016 09:55:13:StackTrace:    at 

FusionCore.PdvSincronizador.Sync.Sincronizador.SincronizarTudo() in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\FusionCore\PdvSincronizador\Sync\Sincronizador.cs:line 79
   at FusionSincronizador.Core.ServicoSincronizadorMain.ExecutarSincronizacao() in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\PdvSincronizador\Core\ServicoSincronizadorMain.cs:line 22
21/02/2016 09:55:13:--- Inner Exception ---
21/02/2016 09:55:13:Mensagem de erro:Transaction not successfully started
21/02/2016 09:55:13:StackTrace:    at FusionCore.PdvSincronizador.Sync.Sincronizador.RealizarSincronizacao(ISincronizacao sincronizacao) in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\FusionCore\PdvSincronizador\Sync\Sincronizador.cs:line 31
   at FusionCore.PdvSincronizador.Sync.Sincronizador.SincronizarTudo() in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\FusionCore\PdvSincronizador\Sync\Sincronizador.cs:line 68
21/02/2016 09:55:13:--- Inner Exception ---
21/02/2016 09:55:13:Mensagem de erro:Transaction not successfully started
21/02/2016 09:55:13:StackTrace:    at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.CheckBegun()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Rollback()
   at FusionCore.PdvSincronizador.Sync.Estrategia.EnviarVendasEcf.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Sincronizar>b__0(VendaEcfDt vendaPdv) in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\FusionCore\PdvSincronizador\Sync\Estrategia\EnviarVendasEcf.cs:line 65
   at NHibernate.Util.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 query, Action`1 method)
   at FusionCore.PdvSincronizador.Sync.Estrategia.EnviarVendasEcf.Sincronizar(DateTime ultimaSincronizacao) in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\FusionCore\PdvSincronizador\Sync\Estrategia\EnviarVendasEcf.cs:line 30
   at FusionCore.PdvSincronizador.Sync.Sincronizador.RealizarSincronizacao(ISincronizacao sincronizacao) in C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Projetos\Fusion\FusionCore\PdvSincronizador\Sync\Sincronizador.cs:line 25
21/02/2016 09:56:14:Serviço iniciou uma sincronização
```

if he had made the rollback and restart the synchronization would have made the next successful

Comment: Your question wording causes it to be hard to understand. May you ask some colleague/friend to help write a better English version?

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood your trouble, it looks like both `SessaoAdm` and `SessaoPdv` yields the same `NHibernate.ITransaction`. Since NHibernate does not launch nested transactions, but instead just yield current transaction when the session's transaction is already started, the second `Rollback` can only fails, finding the transaction is not pending.

Check `SessaoAdm` and `SessaoPdv` are actually distinct `ISession` instances. Maybe the way you have implemented/initialized those properties cause them to yield the same instance.

Check `IsActive` value on both transaction before and after first rollbacck.

Comment: Solution, before commit, execute flush (SessaoAdm.Flush, SessaoPdv.Flush)